# Изменение размеров изображения

Tags: c#, изображения, масштабирование

Пользователь выбирает картинку для своего аватара, например с разрешением 1920 на 1080 и нажимает кнопку загрузить изображение. Картинка превращается в массив `byte[]` и отправляется на сервер. Необходимо на сервере перед записью картинки в таблицу уменьшить ее размер до 100x100 пикселей. И если загружаемое изображение меньше чем 100x100, то не трогать его. Каким образом узнать размер картинки и уменьшить ее при необходимости?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ [**ТУТ**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988090/changing-image-size-from-stream)

Вот правильный ответ:

```
byte[] imageBytes; 

//Of course image bytes is set to the bytearray of your image      

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
    {
        using (Image img = Image.FromStream(ms))
        {
            int h = 100;
            int w = 100;

            using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(img, new Size(w,h)))
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    b.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    imageBytes = ms2.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }                        
    }
```

Comment: Пропорции при этом могут исказиться.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в моем случае это не критично) но я бы с удовольствием хотел узнать как сохранять пропорции изображения)